# How to call async function inside Observable method sequentially?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, rxjs

I have the following method:

```
  public classMethod(
    payload: Payload,
  ): Observable<Result> {
    const { targetProp } = payload;
    let target;

    return this.secondClass.secondClassMethod({ targetProp }).pipe(
      delayWhen(() =>
        // some other actions
      ),
    );
  }
```

It is critical to set this `target` value before calling `this.secondClass.secondClassMethod`.

Is it possible to call regular async method like this:

````
  public classMethod(
    req: classMethodRequest,
  ): Observable<classMethodResponse> {
    const { targetProp } = req;
    let target;

    /**
    **  Calling async method here to set ```target```
    ** like 
    ** target = await someAsyncMethod(targetProp)
    **/

    return this.secondClass.secondClassMethod({ targetProp }).pipe(
      delayWhen(() =>
      ),
      
    );
  }
````

In other words, I would like to invoke method `classMethod` so, that `classMethod` will set `target` variable within it and then it will be possible to use `target` in the returning construction

```
return this.secondClass.secondClassMethod({ targetProp }).pipe(
      delayWhen(() =>
      ),
    );
```

I've tried to cover async method in:

```
 from(
      (async () => {
        target = await this.someAsyncMethod.setTarget(targetProp);
      })(),
    );
```

BUT I was told that this cover will invoke in parallel with

```
return this.secondClass.secondClassMethod({ targetProp }).pipe(
      delayWhen(() =>
      ),
    );
```

parallel is not an option here :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the promise to an observable using [`from`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/from) and use [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap)

```ts
return from(this.someAsyncMethod.setTarget(targetProp)).pipe(
  switchMap(target => this.secondClass.secondClassMethod({ targetProp }),
  delayWhen(() => ... ),
);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for me. By why just writing async call before `return ....` will cause that async and code after return will be called in parallel?

Comment: It shouldn't if you `await` the call before `return`